# Reconstruction of Normal Distribution Function (NDF) using Wheeler's algorithm

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, statistics

I have a polydisperse bubble in liquid simulation which calculates statistical moments, and my next target is to reconstruct the Normal Distribution Function (NDF) that represent bubble size distribution using the moments data. I found this equation to approximate the NDF

$$
n\left(\xi\right)=\sum_{\alpha=0}^{N-1}w_\alpha\delta\left(\xi-\xi_\alpha\right)
$$

but I have no idea how to calculate the weights and abscissas from the calculated moments data. Some sources said that I can calculate it with [Wheeler's algorithm](https://doi.org/10.1216/RMJ-1974-4-2-287). I've read the paper but I found it difficult to understand.

Does anyone know how to calculate the weights and abscissas from statistical moments using Wheeler's algorithm or maybe an example program that performs Wheeler's algorithm? multiphase simulation is a brand new topic for me.

Comment: I am not familiar with the subject, but [this book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/computational-models-for-polydisperse-particulate-and-multiphase-systems/momentinversion-algorithms/A96F440344257882B10D6C89EF1B4331) looks to have what you want, I think (I don't have access to full doc/book).

Comment: thank you @KyleKanos i checked the link and it is the algorithm, perhaps gonna looking for the book to my colleague